# Redirecionamento por href PHP

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma class DAO que contém todos os métodos para executar.
Porém quando o usuário entra no acesso dele, ele faz um select do banco trazendo seus clientes.

Dentro do while eu coloquei

Minha duvida é: como vou chamar a class DAO e a função excluir que contém nela?

Exemplo que já fiz e não funcionou

```
echo "<td><a href='UsuarioDAO.php?excluir=$id'><button>Clique</button></td> </a>";

class UsuarioDAO(){

public function excluir(){
//codigo vem aqui
}

}
```

Comment: Creio que falta pegar o valor passado pela URL via `get`....

Comment: Outro detalhe é que há um erro de sintaxe no html....

Answer (score 3):

No arquivo **UsuarioDAO.php**, coloque algo assim:

```
class UsuarioDAO(){

    public function excluir($id){
        //codigo vem aqui
        echo 'ID para excluir: '.$id;
    }

}

/*
Verifica o parâmetro recebido pela URL
*/
$method = 'excluir';
if (isset($_GET[$method])) {
    $id = trim(strip_tags($_GET[$method]));
}

/*
Instancia a classe e invoca o método se existir
*/
$c = new UsuarioDAO;
if (method_exists($c, $method)) {
    $c->{$method}($id);
} else {
    echo 'Método não existe: '.$method;
}
```

Comment: Acredito que a pessoa que negativou sua resposta fez isso por causa dessa linha: $method = 'excluir'; Retire isso que fica uma resposta de boa. Dei um +1 pela sua boa vontade em ajudar o cara e para neutralizar o voto negativo embora eu nunca faria um link acessar diretamente o DAO.  Ele devia chamar um controlador  e este sim chamar o DAO. No entanto sua resposta tem um fragmento muito valioso que é o if method_exist e esse mérito ninguém pode tirar da sua resposta.

Comment: Lembrando tb ao autor da pergunta que deve-se usar um prepared statement do PDO ou mysqli real escape string pra limpar a variável id e passar o valor do id  para a query sql de forma segura.